# how to align logo with nav bar

Tags: css

how to align logo with nav bar? i just need to align the logo in my navigation bar because i can't use margin and padding it only applies in one page. Please help me here's my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-left disabled" href="#" >
    <?php 
      if (file_exists ('images/logo.jpg')) 
      {
         echo' <img src="images/logo.jpg"  alt="" width="30px" height="30px" style="margin-top:6px"'; 
      } 
      else 
      { 
        echo''; 
      }
    ?>
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php"> 
    <?php echo "&nbsp;".$x; ?>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you please provide a working sample?

Comment: i can't put my logo cause i'm only using include :( i'm confused because i can't align my logo to my nav bar. my logo always left in margin top whenever i edit my margin-top in only applies on one page

Comment: i was about to upload a example photo but i can't upload until i get 10 reputation.

Comment: make use of jsfiddle.net

Comment: @MigsMartin Just remove your `php`-code and add the image tag with a example image. Do you use bootstrap?

Comment: @patrick yes i use bootstrap. how to add image tag? sorry im just new in this site.

Comment: @lara thankyou for your reply i will use it now :) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're searching for?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- You already have this, dont copy this -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-left disabled" href="#">

      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php">
        <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" width="30" height="30">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

If yes, here's the code with your `php`-code inside.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-left disabled" href="#">

      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php">
        <?php 
            if (file_exists ('images/logo.jpg')) {
                echo '<img src="images/logo.jpg" width="30" height="30">'; 
            } 
                else 
            { 
                echo ''; 
            }
        ?>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: my logo is still stuck at top i need to align it with my navigation bar so every time i change my page the logo is still align to my nav bar.

Comment: thank you sir! Your code helped me :) i'll use this for now thanks for the help i can go home now :D God Bless you!

Comment: @LaraBelle I just copied the code from the question from the OP, dunno why he's using this.